# Angular 7 - Criar um Stepper/Wizard

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estou fazendo uma página de cadastro, cuja qual está funcionando. Eu queria mudar ela para um Stepper/Wizard, mas estou usando Angular 7 com Bootstrap 4.

Alguém já fez um ou tem um exemplo em angular?

Answer (score 0):

O angular material possui um stepper bem legal, veja:

https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

Basta instalar os pacotes necessários:

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations
```

Importe no app.module:

```
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule],
  ...
})
```

E então importe o componente stepper no seu módulo, conforme mostra a documentação:

```
import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material/stepper';
```

Exemplo no [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ekxdngqajxa?file=app%2Fstepper-overview-example.ts)

Comment: No Material eu achei no google, mas precisa ser no bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei uma biblioteca chamada bs-stepper, que utiliza Bootstrap 4.

Instalei ele no projeto conforme fala na documentação: [bs-stepper instalacao](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bs-stepper)

Tem um exemplo funcional neste link: [bs-stepper exemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bs-stepper-angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Alguns detalhes que precisei fazer para funcionar foi:

1- importar o **import Stepper from 'bs-stepper';** apenas no component que irá utilizar o stepper, APENAS NELE!

2- Incluir os arquivos de css e js no angular.json

```js
            "styles": [
              "projects/permissoes/src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bs-stepper/dist/js/bs-stepper.min.js"
            ]
```

Ou importar o css no arquivo **styles.css** do projeto:

```css
@import "~bs-stepper/dist/css/bs-stepper.css";
```